# Enabling an Internet route through ppp0

Tags: vpn, route, pptp

I have Debian 8.0.0-64 running on my server, which has `eth1` as the interface with the default gateway. `eth0` is pointing to the internal network.

```
root@server:/home/user# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:46:7e:88:72:d7  
          inet addr:10.168.118.205  Bcast:10.168.118.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::446:7eff:fe88:72d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15215 (14.8 KiB)  TX bytes:79027 (77.1 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:70:65:5f:e9:89  
          inet addr:167.41.133.218  Bcast:167.41.133.223  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::470:65ff:fe5f:e989/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:46420 (45.3 KiB)  TX bytes:33486 (32.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:706 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:86847 (84.8 KiB)  TX bytes:86847 (84.8 KiB)
```

I set up a VPN (TotalVPN) connection using the following instructions:
http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml#configure_by_hand

With `pon amsterdam` I can actually open a tunnel:

```
root@server:/home/user# pon amsterdam

root@server:/home/user# ifconfig
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.126.0.29  P-t-P:10.126.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:66 (66.0 B)
```

So far so good. Now I'd love to be able to ping, e.g., google.com (`ping -I ppp0 google.com`) through the tunnel, without losing the possibility to use `eth1` as my default interface (`ping google.com`). How can I setup a `route` or whatever needed, so that traffic (to the internet) can be going through the tunnel, if specifically asked for, i.e., by defining the interface `ppp0` to be used?

Here is some information (the name of the VPN connection is `amsterdam`):

```
root@server:/home/user# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         167.41.133.209  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.168.118.193  255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.168.118.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
161.26.0.0      10.168.118.193  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
167.41.133.208  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1

root@server:/home/user# pon amsterdam

root@server:/home/user# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.168.118.193  255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.126.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.168.118.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
45.32.239.20    167.41.133.209  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
161.26.0.0      10.168.118.193  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
167.41.133.208  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1

root@server:/home/user# poff amsterdam

root@server:/home/user# route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         167.41.133.209  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.168.118.193  255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.168.118.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
45.32.239.20    167.41.133.209  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
161.26.0.0      10.168.118.193  255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
167.41.133.208  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1

root@server:/home/user#
```

---

I found two solutions, which worked on the first view, but they really don't work (and I don't know why).

1. Adding `route add default metric 10 gw $PPP_REMOTE $PPP_IFNAME` in the up-script, or
2. add `defaultroute` to the pptp configuration

In both cases, calling `curl --interface ppp0 ifconfig.co` as `root` works and returns the IP address of the VPN connection, but I cannot execute the command as any other non-root user. The command `curl --interface eth1 ifconfig.co` works fine as `root` or a normal user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what I wanted to achieve I had to do the following things:

Step 1: Install the PPTP Client Program for Debian Project

Step 2: Setup the PPTP connection

Step 3: Testing the connection

Step 4: Adding the route

Step 5: Final check

For the first three steps, I mainly followed http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml. After doing so, I found this great article (https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System), which explains on how to add two default gateways. The main idea behind the second gateway approach, is to create a ***Second Routing Table*** in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` (in my case I named it `ppp`). After this is done, routes are added to this new table and rules are defined:

```
ip route add 10.10.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.10.0.10 table ppp
ip route add default via 10.10.0.1 dev eth1 table ppp

ip rule add from 10.10.0.10/32 table ppp
ip rule add to 10.10.0.10/32 table ppp
```

After testing, I added the scripts, so that the routes are added and deleted whenever the VPN connection is established, i.e.,

**ip-up script**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$PPP_IPPARAM" = "amsterdam" ] ; then

  /sbin/ip route add $PPP_LOCAL/24 dev $PPP_IFACE src $PPP_LOCAL table ppp
  /sbin/ip route add default via $PPP_REMOTE dev $PPP_IFACE table ppp

  /sbin/ip rule add from $PPP_LOCAL/32 table ppp
  /sbin/ip rule add to $PPP_LOCAL/32 table ppp
fi
```

**ip-down script**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$PPP_IPPARAM" = "amsterdam" ] ; then

  /sbin/ip route del $PPP_LOCAL/24 dev $PPP_IFACE src $PPP_LOCAL table ppp
  /sbin/ip route del default via $PPP_REMOTE dev $PPP_IFACE table ppp

  /sbin/ip rule del from $PPP_LOCAL/32 table ppp
  /sbin/ip rule del to $PPP_LOCAL/32 table ppp
fi
```

That works perfectly and I'm able to pick the second gateway whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `route` or the newer `ip route` to set up routes:

```
ip route
```

shows the existing routes, and

```
ip route del default via 167.41.133.218
ip route add default via 10.126.0.29
```

replaces the default route over `eth1` with a route over `ppp0`

The "if specifically asked for" is a problem - you set routes by destination address, not by program. So if you know which addresses you want to contact via `ppp0`, you can set these addresses as non-default routes.

Alternatively, you can use [network namespaces](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) to have some programs use a different network configuration, but this is not so easy to setup and has some pitfalls (e.g. different resolve.conf are needed).

Comment: I'll look into the network namespaces. The first idea is not really a solution. I need both interfaces to be able to retrieve data from the internet and select the device via the `-i`, `-I`, or `--interface` switch depending on the command or application I'm using.

Comment: Can you give examples of what commands or applications you intend to use? The majority of them doesn't have any sort of `--interface` switch, and because of the way networking works, it's impossible to add any such switch.

Comment: Of course just linux commands would be `curl`, `ping`, `traceroute`, but I also have a Java application, which supports an interface switch (based on HtmlUnit), which allows to decide which interface to use to retrieve data from a web-site. I don't understand the comment "it's impossible", several linux commands support such a switch (as mentioned before) and I have seen servers supporting multiple interfaces facing the internet and using exactly these and other commands (just don't know how they are configured).

Answer (score 1):

Simple bash script to access the internet from ppp0-vpn

```
## Instruction to Use
- Once you are connected to ppp0-VPN
- Run this bash script. Command shared below
> chmod +x router-ppp0toint.sh
> ./router-ppp0toint.sh
```

router-ppp0toint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(ifconfig ppp0 | grep inet | cut -d: -f2 |awk '{print $2}') #IP assigned post connected to ppp0 VPN

echo $IP  #echos ppp0 IP

route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw $IP dev ppp0 

route add -net 172.16.0.0 gw $IP netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0 #add static route

route add -net 192.168.0.0 gw $IP netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0
```

[Github-Bash Script for internet in ppp0-vpn](https://github.com/rishuranjanofficial/vpn-ppp0-scripts/blob/master/router-ppp0toint.sh)

Comment: Not only are `ifconfig` and `route` deprecated, this only sets route to private address ranges.