# SonicWall NetExtender not working

Tags: debian, networking, vpn, ppp, pppd

I recently moved to another company. I had to format my computer, so I decided to test Debian 11. But now I'm facing some issues with VPN. I can't connect to any site that's only is available under VPN. They use SonicWall NetExtender. I've got some logs but it doesn't provides any clues about what is happening...

```
04/20/2022 20:25:55.411 [connect info    14505] User:   <username>
04/20/2022 20:25:55.411 [connect info    14505] Domain: <domain>
04/20/2022 20:25:55.411 [connect info    14505] Server: <server>
04/20/2022 20:25:55.457 [general notice  14505] Connecting to <server>...
04/20/2022 20:25:55.554 [general notice  14505] Connected.
04/20/2022 20:25:55.554 [general notice  14505] Logging in...
04/20/2022 20:25:55.645 [general notice  14505] Login successful.
04/20/2022 20:25:55.806 [general error   14505] Version header not found
04/20/2022 20:25:55.806 [epc     info    14505] Server don't support EPC check. Just pass EPC check
04/20/2022 20:25:55.806 [general warn    14505] WireGuard is not capable, root permission is required.
04/20/2022 20:25:55.907 [connect notice  14505] Try to connect with SSLVPN...
04/20/2022 20:25:56.160 [general notice  14505] SSL Connection is ready
04/20/2022 20:25:57.166 [general info    14505] Using new PPP frame encoding mechanism
04/20/2022 20:25:57.167 [general info    14505] Using PPP async mode (chosen by server) 
04/20/2022 20:25:57.167 [general info    14505] Connecting tunnel...
04/20/2022 20:26:00.282 [connect info    16154] PPP interface up
04/20/2022 20:26:01.282 [dns     notice  16154] Setting up DNS
04/20/2022 20:26:01.296 [general info    16154] Setting up DNS suffixes
04/20/2022 20:26:01.301 [general info    16172] Monitoring processes:  nx=14505, pppd=16132
04/20/2022 20:26:01.301 [dns     info    16172] Monitoring nameserver: <ip>
04/20/2022 20:26:01.301 [dns     info    16172] Monitoring nameserver: <ip>
04/20/2022 20:26:01.301 [dns     info    16172] Monitoring DNS suffix: <dns>
04/20/2022 20:26:01.301 [dns     info    16172] Monitoring DNS suffix: <dns>
04/20/2022 20:26:02.262 [general info    14505] Client IP Address: <ip>
04/20/2022 20:26:02.262 [general info    14505] You now have access to the following 25 remote networks:
04/20/2022 20:26:02.262 [general info    14505] [redacted information]
04/20/2022 20:26:02.264 [general notice  14505] NetExtender connected successfully.
04/20/2022 20:26:02.412 [general info    14505] Saving profiles/preferences...
04/20/2022 20:26:02.412 [general info    14505] Done saving profiles/preferences
```

Apparently I'm connected but I can't reach any site that's depends on VPN.

EDIT:

As suggested in [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699796/sonicwall-netextender-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1322894_699796)

```bsh
# ip route
default via <my ip> dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
<vpn ip 1>/16 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 2> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 3> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 4> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 5> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 6> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 7> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 8> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 9> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 10>/16 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 11>/16 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 12>/16 dev wlp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
<vpn ip 12>/12 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 14>/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src <ip 1> linkdown 
<vpn ip 15> via <my ip> dev wlp4s0 
<vpn ip 16> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 17> dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src <client vpn ip> 
<ip 2>/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src <ip 3> metric 600 
<my ip> dev wlp4s0 scope link 
<vpn ip 18>/24 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 19>/22 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 20>/23 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 21>/23 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 22>/22 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 23>/24 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 24>/23 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 25>/23 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 26>/24 via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 27> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0 
<vpn ip 28> via <client vpn ip> dev ppp0

# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:8a:e1:d8:d2:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:cd:5b:52:8e:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:16:bf:bb:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 

# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:8a:e1:d8:d2:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:cd:5b:52:8e:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <ip 1>/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp4s0
       valid_lft 11638sec preferred_lft 11638sec
    inet6 2804:7f0:b980:7174:f5b5:34f3:be57:c90e/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43170sec preferred_lft 43170sec
    inet6 fe80::f9c3:d2a:431f:b878/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:16:bf:bb:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet <client vpn ip> peer <vpn ip 17>/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `ip route;ip link;ip address`. Read `man ip ip-route ip-link ip-address`

Comment: Edited, I've omitted the IP itself but put an annotation equivalent in each output.

Comment: I found a workaround using https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315813/523003